# Application to run and test all the supported features of nVidia GPU

Tags: windows, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

Is there any Windows application that will attempt to run all the supported features of a nVidia GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Does the nTune tool not give you the information you need? Which feature(s) are you specifically looking for? Because, while the Nvidia drivers/ graphics card needs to support the feature, more importantly, the OS and application needs to support the features.

Comment: Well, nVidia seems to support all the available features on Windows, so I've mentioned Windows. I just want to be able to trigger all the features supported by the card available.

Comment: From the Nvidia side, that just means having the correct drivers.  On the OS and Application side, that gets a little more complex. You aren't going to find NVidia blocking features in general. Rather you'll run into applications that are properly configured to take **advantage** of the features.

Comment: Yes well, it would be great if Nvidia could provide an application that does. I want to see them in action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [3DMark](http://www.3dmark.com/) from [Futuremark](http://futuremark.com/), it's great for benchmarking the display cards capabilities.